# Why is the array index out of bounds?

Tags: java

I need to convert the contents of a 2D char array to a string, and surround it with borders. Each box will be different with whatever method is called. Whenever I run the client I get the error java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 4 on line 107 (marked in the code ) and I don't know why. Any ideas on what's wrong?

```
public class TwoDArrayFiller
{
        private char [][] array;

public TwoDArrayFiller(char[][] dataArray) 
{
    array = new char[dataArray.length][dataArray[0].length];
    for(int i = 0; i < dataArray.length ; i++ )
    {
        for( int j = 0; j < dataArray[0].length ; j++ )
        {
            array[i][j] = dataArray[i][j];
        }
    }
} //end constructor

public void fillRows()
{

    for ( int i = 0; i < array.length ; i+=2 ) 
    {
        for( int j = 0; j < array[i].length; j++ )
        {
            array[i][j] = 'X';
        }
    }
} // end fillRows
public void fillColumns()
{

for( int i = 0; i < array.length; i++ )
{
    for (int j = 0; j < array[0].length; j+=2 )
    {
        array[i][j] = 'X';
    }
}

} // end fillcolumns
public void border()
{

    for( int i = 0; i < array.length; i++ )
    {   
        for( int j = 0; j < array[0].length; j++ )
        {
            if ( i == 1 || i == 2 )
            {
                array[i][j] = 'X';
                j+=2;
            }
            else
            {

                array[i][j] = 'X';
            }
        }
    }
}// end border
public String toString()
{
    String output = new String();

    for( int i = 0; i < array.length + 2; i++ )
    {
        for( int j = 0; j < array[0].length + 2; j++ )
        {
            if( ( i == 0 && j == 0 ) || (i == 0 && j == ( array[0].length + 2 )) )
            {
                output = output + "+";
                if ( j == ( array[0].length + 2 ) )
                output = output + "\n";                                         
            }
            else if( i == ( array.length + 2 ) && j == 0 )
            {
                output = output + "+";
            }
            else if( ( i == 0 && j == ( array[0].length + 2 ) ) || ( i == 5 && j == ( array[0].length + 2 ) ))
            {
                output = output + "+\n";
            }
            else if ( i == 0 || i == ( array[0].length + 2 ) )
            {
                output = output + "-";
            }
            else if( j == 0 || j == ( array[0].length + 2 ) )
            {
                output = output + "|";
                if( j == ( array[0].length + 2 ) )
                {
                    output = output + "\n";
                }
                else{
                }
            }
            else
            {
                output = output + array[i - 1][j - 1]; // here is where the error occurs
            }
        }
    }
    return output;
}// end tostring
}
```

Comment: Please edit your question to state which line the exception is occurring on - the stacktrace will tell you this information.

Comment: Because it is. This is where one - i.e. you - gets to learn about debugging. Yay! Which line causes said exception? On which value(s)? Why?

Comment: i < array.length + 2 and then array[i-1][j-1]

Comment: You could think of a more elegant way of writing a box-printing algorithm. Think - print required box top and left, print array, print box right and bottom.. just saying :) anyway do debugging (even simple system.out.println debugging) to find the problem. It must be what sashkello points out.

Comment: I have rolled back your question. Don't completely change your question to be the final answer. If you have an answer to give, make it an actual answer. And please don't use the [homework] tag. It is obsolete and in the process of being removed.

Answer (score 2):

This is something that I would change:

```
for( int i = 0; i < array.length + 2; i++ )
```

array.length + 2 means you want to "point" outside the array

Answer (score 2):

In your else statement:

```
else
            {
                output = output + array[i - 1][j - 1];
            }
```

you're accessing array[i-1][j-1], but you've said i can go up to array.length+2, making this point to array[array.length+1], which would be out of bounds.

Answer (score 1):

In the toString function, your i can go up to array.length + 1, but then
array[i-1] will be out of bounds and yet in the else clause you access array[i-1][j-1]. Boom!